# Post method is not sending JWT in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I'm using post man to test my route and I dont know why it is not sending token to the database.
Any suggestions?

```
//Add new user A.K.A Registration

app.post('/addUser', (req, res) => {
    const addUser = new User({username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password})
    addUser.save().then(result => res.status(200).json(result).catch((err) => console.log(err)))
    jwt.sign(addUser,'secretkey',{expiresIn:'30h'},(err,token)=>{
        res.json(token)
    })
})
```

Comment: where are you sending token to database? Instead you are sending response two times.

Comment: Thank you for the response,I don't really know where to take token and thats why i thought i had to send it with registrated user

Comment: Yes, you have to send it with the registered user but make it a single response. Then save the token on client side and send it with every request in the authorization header to the protected route.

Comment: So addUser,save() is not neccesary anymore

Comment: you would need it to save user's data in the database. see my answer I hope you can get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending response twice that's why you are not gettin token in response from a request in postman. Try this code.

```
app.post('/addUser', (req, res) => {
    const addUser = new User({username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password})
    addUser.save()
    .then( result => {
          jwt.sign(addUser,'secretkey',{expiresIn:'30h'},(err,token)=>{
                  res.status(200).json(result,token);
          })
    }
    .catch((err) => console.log(err)))
})
```